# nginx rewrite not working, but not sure why

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I must be missing something really stupid here, but I can't see it. I have the following URL format:

```
https://www.example.com/french/xx/cats_59_H_L.html
```

...and this rule:

```
rewrite ^/french/.*/cats_([0-9]+)_([A-Z])_([A-Z])\.html$ /cgi-bin/hotels/related_cats.cgi?ID=$1&start=$2&end=$3&type=chambres&t=french last;
```

However, it gives a 404:

```
2017/08/30 12:52:59 [error] 8041#8041: *1147655 open() "/home/user/web/example.com/public_html/french/xx/cats_59_H_L.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.174.134.133, server: example.com, request: "GET /french/xx/cats_59_H_L.html HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com"
```

UPDATE: OK, well I have found the offending rule, but I'm trying to work out how to get around it.

```
location /french {
    include /home/fatpeter/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/other-cats-french.conf;
}
```

My main config for the domain is:

```
server {
    listen      111.74.193.98:443 http2;
    listen      [::]:443 http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root        /home/user/web/example.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/user/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/user/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    if ($host = "example.com") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {

        include     /home/user/conf/web/nginx.example.com.rules.conf*;

        ssi on;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ \.cgi$ {
            gzip off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;

        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/user/web/example.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/user/web/example.com/stats/;
        include /home/user/web/example.com/stats/auth.conf*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/user/conf/web/nginx.example.com.conf*;
}
```

As you can see, we have this here:

```
include     /home/user/conf/web/nginx.example.com.rules.conf*;
```

That file contains:

```
include     /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/301-redirects.conf;
include     /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/glinks-rules.conf;
```

...and then inside **301-redirects.conf**, we have:

```
location /french/Gites {
    include /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/gites-cats-french.conf;
}
location /Gites {
    include /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/gites-cats-english.conf;
}

location /french/Chambres_D_Hotes {
    include /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/chambres-cats-french.conf;
}
location /Chambres_D_Hotes {
    include /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/chambres-cats-english.conf;
}

location /french {
    include /home/user/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/other-cats-french.conf;
}
```

The reason I did it that way, is because we have over 30,000 rewrites for one of the top level categories, and 20,000 rules in another one - so I wanted to split it up to save on the load.

The only way I've found around this, is to do:

```
location /french {
    rewrite ^/french/.*/cats_([0-9]+)_([A-Z])_([A-Z])\.html$ /cgi-bin/hotels/related_cats.cgi?ID=$1&start=$2&end=$3&type=chambres&t=french last;
    include /home/fatpeter/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/other-cats-french.conf;
}
```

I guess that's because one block is stopping the other one from running, so they need to be in the same block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, nginx isn't seeing the rewrite. The regex looks correct to me, so I'd look to see if it's in the correct place in your nginx configuration and that your URI isn't being picked up by another location or something.

**EDIT:**
Judging by your use case of multiple includes for 301's, my suggestion would be to move all of these to a `map`. It may potentially make it a bit quicker too.

For example:

```
map $uri $is_rewrite {
    default     no_redirect;
    "~/regex" "/kitten";
    #...
};
server {
    #...
    if ($is_rewrite != no_redirect) {
        rewrite .? $is_redirect permanent;
    }
    #...
}
```

The easiest way would be to just pop it into the file that you're including from the `/french` location. Just thought I'd mention maps as it might make your life easier :)

Comment: Thanks - I thought it looks right. I'll give a play around and see what I can find. Some awkward with rewrites in nginx, and debugging which blocks are picking up / overwriting other rules :(

Comment: If you can, edit your post with more of your nginx config, and I'll edit my answer appropriately :)

Comment: I found the problem. I've updated my question above

Comment: I've updated my answer ;) I hope that helps @op.

Comment: thanks - will take a look at the "map" stuff. Does seem interesting :)

Comment: with the map stuff, can I make it include an extra file? The reason I ask, is that I use VestaCP as the management tool for the server. This in turn creates a snginx.conf and nginx.conf file based on a template. I don't really want to have to edit and rebuild that every time I make a tweak - so I'm wondering if there is a way to include a list of rules?

Comment: You need to have an `include` statement in the `http` level of nginx configuration. If your VestaCP does not support it, then you need to get rid of it...

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that isn't the problem. I can happily add in extra code to the template - I was more saying that I wanted a way to include a list of the rules, instead of having to update the main config file every time :)

Comment: `include` can be referenced at any level, if there are no other constraints. Here the `include` is used to include `map` statements, which must be in `http` context. I didn't explicitly state this in my comment because the context for my comment is the answer above.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - my bad. You're right. Removed my comment for not wanting to mislead people in future. OP - Tero is correct. you will need to pop your maps in maps.conf or something and include it at the http level. But you can reference it then at a later date (see the above answer)